# How to make an indexed column go through an apply function?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in which I have removed unknowns, NaN and other str type values. I have created a simple function that converts a str type column into a float type by removing a comma. This works alone, however, when I add the index column the apply function will not work. I need the index column in order to have the groupby 'NERC Region' in a later step after I have converted the 'Number of Customers Affected' into float type. If this is not done, there will be a mismatch in the number of rows between NERC Region and Number of Customers Affected. How can I have two columns undergo apply?

```
power4 = power[power.get('Number of Customers Affected') != 'Unknown'] 
power5 = power4[pd.notnull(power4['Number of Customers Affected'])] 
power6 = power5[power.get('Number of Customers Affected') != 'UNK'] 
power7 = power6[power.get('Number of Customers Affected') != 'Major Industrial Customer Load Reduction'] 
power8 = power7[power6.get('NERC Region') == 'RFC'] 
power9 = power8.set_index('NERC Region') 
power10 = power9.get('Number of Customers Affected').loc[1] 
power11 = float(power10.replace(',','')) 
def convert_to_float(number):
   number2 = float(number.replace(',',''))
   return number2 
power9.get("Number of Customers Affected").apply(convert_to_float)
```

[image]

```
{'Event Description': {0: 'Severe Weather - Thunderstorms',
  1: 'Severe Weather - Thunderstorms',
  7: 'Severe Weather - Thunderstorms',
  12: 'Severe Weather - Thunderstorms',
  30: 'Severe Weather - Heavy Winds'},
 'Year': {0: 2014, 1: 2014, 7: 2014, 12: 2014, 30: 2014},
 'Time Event Began': {0: '8:00 PM',
  1: '11:20 PM',
  7: '5:00 PM',
  12: '9:50 PM',
  30: '6:00 PM'},
 'Date of Restoration': {0: '7/2/2014',
  1: '7/1/2014',
  7: '6/20/2014',
  12: '6/11/2014',
  30: '5/11/2014'},
 'Time of Restoration': {0: '6:30 PM',
  1: '5:00 PM',
  7: '3:00 PM',
  12: '2:30 PM',
  30: '1:00 PM'},
 'Respondent': {0: 'Exelon Corporation/ComEd',
  1: 'Northern Indiana Public Service Company',
  7: 'Detroit Edison Co',
  12: 'American Electric Power',
  30: 'Vectren Energy Delivery of Indiana'},
 'Geographic Areas': {0: 'Illinois',
  1: 'North Central Indiana',
  7: 'Southeast Michigan',
  12: 'West Virginia',
  30: 'Indiana'},
 'NERC Region': {0: 'RFC', 1: 'RFC', 7: 'RFC', 12: 'RFC', 30: 'RFC'},
 'Number of Customers Affected': {0: '420,000',
  1: '127,000',
  7: '138,802',
  12: '66,383',
  30: '56,000'},
 'Tags': {0: 'severe weather, thunderstorm',
  1: 'severe weather, thunderstorm',
  7: 'severe weather, thunderstorm',
  12: 'severe weather, thunderstorm',
  30: 'severe weather, wind'}}
```

Desired output(after group by):

```
[NERC Region] [Numbers of Customers Affected]
 RFC               43233445
 MRO                3234432
 SERC               66445544
 MAIN               89832983
 etc.                 etc.
```

Comment: Do you have a sample from the dictionary which can be used to make the data frame? When you say you add index column and then it does not work - do you mean NERC Region is turned to index column?

Comment: Yes, the NERC Region is turned to index column.

Comment: Can you pls take your final data frame before removing comma, paste the o/p of   df.head().to_dict() in the description and also the desired out put?

Comment: have posted an answer ....apply is not needed just to replace the comma or to convert to float. pls accept if that is what you are looking for....let me know if that does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Original Dataframe: (I inserted some 'unknown' and nan values randomly under 'Number of Customers' column)

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Number of Customers Affected'] = df['Number of Customers Affected'].str.replace(",","").str.replace("[Uu]nknown","0").astype('float')
df.set_index('NERC Region', inplace = True)
df.groupby(level = 0)[['Number of Customers Affected']].sum()
df
```

Please note there is only one region in the sample data - thats why it is showing one. The o/p below:

[image]

Comment: power4 = power
power4['Number of Customers Affected'] = ['Number of Customers Affected'].str.replace(",","").astype('float')
power4.set_index('NERC Region', inplace = True)
power4.groupby(level = 0)[['Number of Customers Affected']].sum()

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-32b20d37f6f7> in <module>
     15 
     16 power4 = power
---> 17 power4['Number of Customers Affected'] = ['Number of Customers Affected'].str.replace(",","").astype('float')
     18 #power4.set_index('NERC Region', inplace = True)
     19 #power4.groupby(level = 0)[['Number of Customers Affected']].sum()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: power4['Number of Customers Affected'] =['Number of Customers Affected'].str.replace(",","").astype('float')    ----> You are missing the power4 on the right hand side. it should be power4['Number of Customers Affected'].str.replace(",","").astype('float')

Comment: The problem is that it has 'unknowns', 'NaN' and several other str types.

Comment: power4 = power
power4['Number of Customers Affected'] = power4['Number of Customers Affected'].str.replace(",","").astype('float')
power4.set_index('NERC Region', inplace = True)
power4.groupby(level = 0)[['Number of Customers Affected']].sum()

Comment: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Unknown'

Comment: I see. By any chance you can put the complete data set - the dictionary anywhere - may be on a github link. I can test and suggest. Alternatively, you may like to convert the NaNs to 0 using fillna method and then convert everything to float.

Comment: I have edited my answer - to replace the unknowns. pls check if it works now. I am not sure what other non-number values are there in that column though as i do not have the complete data set.